# Search specific data [POSTGRES]

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, psql

How to display a user's login time, the name of the machine with which it is connected, the operating system and the program from which it was opened.

I found this query to select active connections, but I do not know where I can find the rest of the information:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

any ideas?. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the rest of that information. You have what you see in `pg_stat_activity`, and that's all. PostgreSQL doesn't endevour to find out the host's OS. If you need it, create a user table and write to it when the user connects.

That said, you ask about

- program, it tells you that in `pg_stat_activity.application_name`.
- user's login time, it tells you that in `pg_stat_activity.usename`,
- name of the machine, it tells you that in `pg_stat_activity.client_hostname`